# NEWB My first SQL Join Query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm working through an SQL text book. Also, I have a CMS driven PHP/SQL website. I have downloaded a copy of my db as I have an understanding of what the correct query results should be when "exploring".

My website has an "alerts" feature where a person can sign up for alerts and then they receive email notifications each time new content is added.

In particular there are two tables: *alert* and *alert_sent*. *Alert* contains the email address of the individuals and *alert_sent* contains details of each email sent to a person. So, if I have say 100 people signed up in my alerts table the table has 100 records. If, for simplicity, there have been ten new articles, a total of 1,000 alert emails have been sent - 10 to each recipient.

When I login to the back end of my CMS website I can see the number of alert emails that a person has received. I'd like to try to recreate this and, I think, I'm almost there.

To obtain all relevant records I ran this query:

```
SELECT alert.alert_recipient,alert_sent.id
FROM alert
INNER JOIN alert_sent
ON alert_sent.alert_id=alert.id;
```

Now that I have that I would like to query this query to show those people who have received the most email alerts. Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT, alert_recipient, ID) FROM myqueryabove
GROUP BY alert_recipient
ORDER id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I have some experience with MS Access where I would just save the query by giving it a name and then running a query against it.

I tried that here:

```
SELECT alert.alert_recipient,alert_sent.id
    -> FROM alert
    -> INNER JOIN alert_sent
    -> ON alert_sent.alert_id=alert.id
    -> AS query_001;
```

But that returned

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

How would I query my query to say return a list of the ten email addresses (alert_recipient) who have received the most email alerts?

__ *UPDATE FOLLOWING SOME ANSWERS****_*_**
In addition to producing the desired results as specified in the last sentence, my goal is to understand how to query an existing query. I like the idea of bite size snippets of code which can later be queried as if they were tables, as opposed to trying to put it all in the same query. This is a product of my learning in Access. It could be that I'm approaching SQL incorrectly? Is this approach possible in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (and don't forget to vote ;)  )

```
    select a.alert_recipient
    from alert
    join
    (
        select top 10
        alert_id,
        count(distinct alert_id)
        from alert_sent
        group by alert_id
        order by count(distinct alert_id)
    )t
    on a.id = t.alert_id
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer but that produced an error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10 alert_id, count(distinct alert_id) from alert_sent"
But, even if it did work my aim was to understand how to query an existing query. I started learning DBs with Access and this may be the source of the way my understanding works. Updating the original Q...

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try something like following (it can work for SQL SERVER 2008):

```
select top 10 alert.alert_recipient, count(alert.alert_recipient) as alert_sent_count 
from alert,  alert_sent
where alert.id = alert_sent.alert_id
group by alert.alert_recipient
order by alert_sent_count desc
```

but for MySql, I have no idea but guessing like:

```
select alert.alert_recipient, count(alert.alert_recipient) as alert_sent_count 
from alert,  alert_sent
where alert.id = alert_sent.alert_id
group by alert.alert_recipient
order by alert_sent_count desc
limit 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but that produced "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10 alert.alert_recipient, count(alert.alert_recipient) as alert_sent_count"

Comment: Can you try this:
=====
select alert.alert_recipient, count(alert.alert_recipient) as alert_sent_count 
from alert,  alert_sent
where alert.id = alert_sent.alert_id
group by alert.alert_recipient
order by alert_sent_count desc
limit 10
======

Comment: That worked! Thanks, the data appear as expected too. I did update my question though. I should have spelled it out more fully. If you have a chance, please see the new bottom paragraph of my Q

Comment: You're welcome! Building your own library is good idea for any language!